# Not all of the input fields are aligned right

Tags: html, css

I have a form and I want to align all input fields and the select field to right line the 1st 5-6 elements. I wrote the following `.css` for the labels:

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

but why only the first elemeents are right aligned ?
I wantto divide the labels and options to two columns

The below is the screenshot of my form.

[image]

HTML code:

```
<span class="screen-reader-text">Gallery Posts Widget</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-title"><h3>Gallery Posts Widget<span class="in-widget-title"></span></h3></div>
    </div>

    <div class="widget-inside">
    <form method="post">    <div class="widget-content">      <p>
      <label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-title">Title:</label>
      <input class="widefat" id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-title"  name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][title]" type="text" value="" />
  </p>

  <p>
      <label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-post_count">Posts to display:</label>
      <input class="small-text" id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-post_count" name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][post_count]" type="number" value="4" />
  </p>
  <p>
      <label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-post_offset">Posts offset:</label>
      <input class="small-text" id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-post_offset" name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][post_offset]" type="number" value="0" />
  </p>

  <p>
      <label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-column_qty">Posts per row:</label>
      <input class="small-text" id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-column_qty" name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][column_qty]" type="number" value="1" />
  </p>
  <p>
      Cell size (px)<br /></small>
      <small><label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-cell_width">Width:</label></small>
      <input class="small-text" id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-cell_width" name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][cell_width]" type="number" value="200" />
      <small><label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-cell_height">Height:</label></small>
      <input class="small-text" id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-cell_height" name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][cell_height]" type="number" value="200" />
  </p>
  <p>
      Gap between<br /></small>
      <small><label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-cell_gap_horizontal">Columns:</label></small>
      <input class="small-text" id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-cell_gap_horizontal" name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][cell_gap_horizontal]" type="text" value="0px" />
      <small><label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-cell_gap_vertical">Rows:</label></small>
      <input class="small-text" id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-cell_gap_vertical" name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][cell_gap_vertical]" type="text" value="0px" />
  </p>


            <p>
          <label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-widget_taxonomy">Taxonomy:</label>
          <select id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-widget_taxonomy"    name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][widget_taxonomy]">
              <option value="">All</option>
                    <option value="category" >Categories (category)</option>
                        <option value="post_tag" >Tags (post_tag)</option>
                        <option value="post_format" >Format (post_format)</option>
                    </select>

      </p>

      <p>
          <label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-taxonomy_term_id">Taxonomy Term IDs:</label>
          <input id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-taxonomy_term_id" name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][taxonomy_term_id]" type="number" value="" />
      </p>

            <p>
          <label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-custom_post_type">Custom Post Type:</label>
          <select id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-custom_post_type"   name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][custom_post_type]">
              <option value="">All</option>
                    <option value="post" >Posts (post)</option>
                        <option value="page" >Pages (page)</option>
                        <option value="attachment" >Media (attachment)</option>
                    </select>

      </p>

  <p>
      <label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-order_field">Order:</label>
          <select id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-order_field"  name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][order_field]">
              <option value="date" >Date</option>
              <option value="title" >Title</option>
              <option value="modified" >Modified Date</option>
              <option value="ID" >ID</option>
              <option value="author" >Author</option>
              <option value="comment_count" >Comment Count</option>
              <option value="rand" >Random</option>
          </select>
          <select id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-order_type"   name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][order_type]">
              <option value="DESC" >Desc</option>
              <option value="ASC" >Asc</option>
          </select>
  </p>
  <p>
      <label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-post_layout">Layout:</label>
      <br />
      <textarea class="widefat" style="resize:none;height:85px" id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-post_layout"    name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][post_layout]"></textarea>
      <br />
      <small>
      Available tags: <br />
      [TITLE] [DATE] [AUTHOR] [EXCERPT] [COMMENT-COUNT] [TAGS] [WOO-PRODUCT-PRICE]
      </small>

  </p>
          <label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-widget_css_class">CSS classes:</label>
          <input id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-widget_css_class" name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][widget_css_class]" type="text" value="" />
  <p>
      <label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-post_date_format">Date Format:</label>
      <input size="12" id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-post_date_format" name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][post_date_format]" type="text" value="F j, Y g:i a" />
  </p>
  <p>
      <label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-post_excerpt_size">Excerpt size (words):</label>
      <input size="3" id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-post_excerpt_size" name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][post_excerpt_size]" type="number" value="10" />
  </p>
  <p>
      <label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-post_excerpt_link">'Read More' Text:</label>
      <input id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-post_excerpt_link" name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][post_excerpt_link]" type="text" value="more&gt;&gt;" />
  </p>
  <p>
```

Comment: please provide code sample or fiddle

Comment: I just want to right align all input types, not only the first 5-6

Comment: ok just add code sample as i mentioned before so we can reach out the problem

Comment: Ok that's the html

Comment: No, that’s PHP. And no one here has your system set-up available so that they could properly execute this to see what the final result will actually be. Please post the _resulting_ HTML code. Even better, create a [mcve], so that people can see what your code does right away without having to make unnecessary extra efforts.

Comment: @CBroe Exactly!

Comment: _“but why only the first elemeents are right aligned ?”_ - because they are _absolutely obviously_ to wide to fit to the right of your 200px wide labels …? Looks like you are simply letting those input elements take the width they want to, resp. get from the browser stylesheet. So _specify_ their (max) width, if you want them to fit into what space remains.

Comment: Ok thanks for description, that's the right html

Comment: add your css for this part as well

Comment: I've added it. I only styled the labels

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add style to the inputs. You only styled the labels. Even those that seem to be right-aligned are not. They just fit there because of the label width and their width.

Comment: Ok help me to style the inputs

Comment: `float: right;` added to those inputs should do it.